# rotate an element within an already rotated element - not working in Firefox

Tags: css, css-transforms

I am rotating an element left by 1 degree. And then rotating the element in it by -1 degree so that the inner element is straight.

Have tested this in Chrome and Safari and it works fine. But in FireFox the inner element rotate is being ignored (still untested in IE).

Any idea what might be wrong?

HTML:

```
<div class="rotated-left">
    <div class="rotated-right">
        <p>This text should be straight.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.rotated-left {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(1deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(1deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(1deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(1deg);
    transform: rotate(1deg);   
}

.rotated-right {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-1deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-1deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-1deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-1deg);
    transform: rotate(-1deg);  
}
```

Comment: Works perfect: http://jsfiddle.net/Lu793/ (Firefox 29).

Comment: Works fine in Firefox 29. Which version of Firefox are you using?

Comment: Ah whoops, I think I realise the problem - I had a second `transform: translate3d(0,0,0)` on the `.rotate-right` which was causing the rotate to be ignored

Answer (score 0):

I tested in chrome, firefox and IE, didn't have issues with any of them. I even removed the browser-specific elements. Still worked.

Make sure you are calling your CSS correctly, maybe?

Comment: Thanks Branton, I figured out I had a second transform which was canceling out the first one.